# AWS App Mesh cross region service communication

Tags: amazon-web-services, envoyproxy, aws-app-mesh

Can I implement communication between 2 services situated in **different AWS regions** using AWS App Mesh? Perhaps, the intention itself is wrong(If so, why?) but I have too little experience in AWS to understand it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide more specific details, the question is too general.

Answer (score 0):

AWS App Mesh doesn't help you achieve this, as an App Mesh exists within a VPC, which exists within a Region.
You'd have to set up VPC Peering https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/peering-scenarios.html

Or make the called service public, which may or may not be appropriate.